# Think of a word which best fits

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to think of a word which best fits in this sentence:

> The truth is nobody really knows how language first began.  Did we all start talking at around the same time _________ of the manner in which our brains had begun to develop?

Can someone help me? I don't even have a slightest idea.

This is from a test.

Comment: I've closevoted as "unclear what you're asking" because (as pointed out by @Mobeer's answer) it's perfectly possible to fill in the blank with words that have precisely opposite meanings. How do we know what concept/word the test setters had in mind? (Which makes it a stupid test, imho.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You'll probably be disappointed but it's from the Cambridge web site. From a sample test of their CAE.

Comment: I certainly *am* disappointed! Particularly given recent discoveries/developments in anthropology that strongly suggest significant differences between how "human" brains began to develop in different regions, periods, and [isolated] gene pools. Unless they provide a list of possible "candidate answers" that doesn't even include any words with meanings like ***regardless, irrespective, independent, in spite of,*** etc., I'd still say it's a stupid test - wherever it came from.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well didn't give a list but the correct answer was indeed **because**.

Comment: Ah well. What can I say? Apart from pointing out that the example sentence also includes the strong implication that "we" *did in fact* all start talking at around the same time (even if we don't know *how* this came about). The fact of the matter is currently we don't even know whether Neanderthals, Denisovans, etc., could "speak", nor do we yet have much idea whether and how their brains differed from *h. sap.* and/or whether interbreeding was a significant factor on that front. So that "implication" is flaky, to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[because](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/because)" - if the test expects you to use common words then this fits.

What is awkward about this sentence is that you could equally fit in a word that has the opposite meaning here:
"[irrespective](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/irrespective)" - but that would be a less common word to use

Comment: I'll try it, hope it fits.